# How can correctly parse a byte stream in R?

Tags: r, rcurl

I am accessing an API which returns a long series of raw bytes.

My Q doesn't lend itself to an easy reprex of the API itself, but here is my best shot:

```
raw_bytes <-
 as.raw(c("0x43","0xb7","0x01","0x48","0x43","0xb7","0x01","0x48","0x43","0xb7","0x01","0x48","0x43","0xb7","0x01","0x48","0x3f","0x80","0x00","0x00","0x00","0x00","0x01","0x5e","0xa9","0x3e","0x83","0x80"))

   > str(raw_bytes)
     raw [1:28] 43 b7 01 48 ...
```

Now, from the API documentation, I know that this 28 byte chunk is to be parsed as follows, with "big" endian-ness:

bytes   type

4    float

4    float

4    float

4    float

4    float

8    Long integer (this is to be a date object, def as milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970)

```
writeBin(raw_bytes, "myfile.txt")

con <- file("myfile.txt", "rb") # create connection object; specify raw binary

> readBin(con, "double", size = 4, n = 5, endian = "big") # get those first 5 objects from the chunk
[1] 366.00 366.00 365.75 366.00  10.70
```

So far so good; these are consistent with what I would expect.

```
> readBin(con, "integer", size = 8, n = 1, endian = "big") # get the last 8 byte chunk
[1] -1453180896
```

Hmmmm that looks wrong.  An online 8 byte hex converter suggests the correct decimal value to be 1506080340000, which matches the date I would expect (Sept 22, 2017)

Taking a closer look at those last 8 bytes:

```
> (con2 <- tail(raw_bytes, 8))

[1] 00 00 01 5e a9 62 38 20
```

And trying a few different stabs at readBin():

```
> readBin(con2, "double", size = 8, n = 1, endian = "big")
[1] 7.441026e-312

> readBin(con2, "numeric", size = 8, n = 1, endian = "little")
[1] 1.818746e-153

> readBin(con2, "integer", size = 8, n = 1, endian = "little")
[1] 1577123840
```

Nope.

I can produce the expected decimal number from these bytes using an outside libary:

```
str <- paste(con2, collapse = "")

> bit64::as.integer64(as.numeric(paste0("0x",str)))
integer64
[1] 1506080340000
```

Anyway, here's my question: is there a way to properly parse my bitstream using base R, particularly readBin()?

And, more generally, is there an opinionated way about how to parse a streaming stream of bytes in an R session?

Comment: To make it reproducible: `con2 = as.raw(c(0x00,0x00,0x01,0x5e,0xa9,0x62,0x38,0x20))`

Comment: Edited; thank you @eddi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an answer to a similar question that you could use:
[reading unsigned integer 64 bit from binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548081/reading-unsigned-integer-64-bit-from-binary-file). It actually also tries to read a date.

A more hacky answer is this:

```
library( bit64 )
con <- file("myfile.txt", "rb")
readBin(con, "double", size = 4, n = 5, endian = "big")
a = readBin(con, "double", size = 8, n = 1, endian = "big")
class(a) = "integer64"
a
# 1506078000000
```

Yuck!
Or:

```
library( bit64 )
con <- file("myfile.txt", "rb")
readBin(con, "double", size = 4, n = 5, endian = "big")
sum( as.integer64( readBin(con,"integer",size=2,n=4,endian="big",signed=F) ) * 
     as.integer64(65536)^(3:0) )
```

Comment: well that works; thank you @user429791.  Still, it is a bit inelegant, as you note.  Out of curiosity, were you already familiar with the bit64 package, or did you wisely intuit that any well crafted package would have this functionality?

Comment: I didn't know the bit64 package. I just converted a number to integer64, and then played around with attributes() to figure out how it is stored. Then I saw that it was just stored as a double, with class=integer64...